# SAP HANA Subquery Visibility

Tags: subquery, hana

I try to get some historical data from the same table. So the table looks like as following:

```
DB1
=======
LID            PID         Date
1              123         2016-01-01
2              123         2015-12-31

DB2
=======
LID         LWID     Description         Value     Time
1           1        abc                 1.0       08:00:00
2           2        abc                 0.8       03:00:00
2           3        abc                 0.5       06:00:00
```

I just need now all different descriptions of a specific PID (the user; 123) with the newest value and the second newest value. both date and time specific. The date is in DB1 and the time in DB2. So our result must be similar to this:

```
PID         Description         newestValue      secondNewestValue
123         abc                 1.0              0.5
```

Here's my query. Works at MySQL.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM "DBSCHEME"."DB1" L
    INNER JOIN "DBSCHEME"."DB2" LW   ON   L."LID" = LW."LID"
    
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT "PID", "Description", MAX("Time"), "Value" 
        FROM "DBSCHEME"."DB1" SL
            INNER JOIN "DBSCHEME"."DB2" SLW ON SL."LID" = SLW."LID"
        WHERE   SL."Date" = '2015-12-31'
        GROUP BY "PID", "Description", "Value"
    ) L1 
        ON  L1."Description" = LW."Description" 
        AND L1."PID" = L."PID"

WHERE L."PID" = 123 AND L."Date" = '2016-01-01'
```

Every Column within the L1-Context is not reachable. That means, that I can't `LEFT JOIN (...) L1 ON L1."Description"`, because `"Description"` is unknown at this position. Again, this works on MySQL.

The error I get is:

> Error: (dberror) 383 - invalid identifier: Description: line 13 col 12

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No error in the SQL, but the SELECT makes little sense. Can you explain exactly what you want? The newest value of relative to which keys, and under which conditions?

Comment: No errors produced by the SQL. https://gist.github.com/flaschbier/4fd65b4451884863d181535e25aff0b3 Please fix the question to either show code that produces error or explain objective.

Comment: your table DB1 has the date listed as '2015-31-12' and the subquery is filtering for a date of '2015-12-31'. Do you see an issue with this or is this a typo in your question?

Comment: thank you for all your answers. it seems like, that this is SAP HANA specific. the error is not caused by the data model nor the data itself - the error is produced, because the engine is not able to see the data within the L1-Context

Comment: Sorry, but no. SAP HANA evaluates the SELECT without issues and does **not** throw an error message. See attached Gist. Everyone can test it in their own free HANA Cloud Platform trial account.